# I can't save a variable from a function (<motion>)

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to save my variable `list_cord` out of the function callback.

```
from tkinter import *
def test():
    root=Tk()
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(1280, 720))
    def callback(event):
        x=event.x
        y=event.y
        list_cord=[x,y]
        print("x=%s,y=%s"%(x,y))
    root.bind("<Motion>", callback)
    #print(list_cord)  # How can i get the values of lista here.(global doesn't work)
    root.mainloop()
test()
```

When I use `global list_cord` above `list_cord=[x,y]` and then the print says me `list_cord is not defined`.
I'm a little new on this (and in my english) ,but I need help on this.
Thanks

Comment: When you `bind` your callback it will be called when the binded action (motion in this case) happens - there would be no x/y data to speak of before that so what you're asking for makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to save the actual place of the cursor, but I can't save the values out of the function callback

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the current mouse position you don't need to set up a `<Motion>` listener to grab the position as you move the mouse, you can just grab it from `winfo`:

```
root = Tk()
list_cord = [root.winfo_pointerx(), root.winfo_pointery()]
print(list_cord)
```

If you want to continuously monitor the mouse position, you'll have to do it from within the `callback` function because its outer scope will finish executing and enter the `Tk.mainloop()` block before the `callback` even gets called.

Comment: This don't work for me, because that is for the screen, and is just one result. I need all the movements of the cursor on my Tk(). I have the callback() but I can't save the values out of the function .

Comment: @FelipeCofré - Then your code should work just fine - as I said above, if you want to do it continuously do it from within the `callback` function.